# Displaying the function's name in the search fields in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to display the function name in search fields in Django Admin interface but when i do it

The models.py:

```
class Adult(models.Model):    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
    def Parent_Name(self):
      try:
        return '%s %s' % (adult.firstname,adult.lastname)
      except Exception:
        return ''
    getParentName.shot_description = 'adult'
```

Admin.py:

```
class AdultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Parent_Name', 'Student_Name',)
    search_fields = ['Parent_Name',]

admin.site.register(Adult, AdultAdmin)
```

Error:
    Cannot resolve keyword 'Parent_Name' into field.

What should be the correct way of writing this so that the function name can be used for search_fields?

Comment: What do you mean using the function name in the search_field?

Comment: i can display, in this case, Parent_Name in the list_display but when i do the same for search_fields, it gives me that error...

Comment: `search_fields` is supposed to be a list of field names indicating which fields in your model are to be searched when the admin search bar is used. It's got nothing to do with displaying labels etc.

Comment: I understand that.. my question is whether u can change to point to the function, instead of the fields of the model? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`search_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) should be:

> ... set to a list of field names that will be searched whenever somebody submits a search query in that text box.

You can't specify your own search function, as it only accepts a list of strings indicating the fields you want to search (unlike the `list_display` option that you have mentioned which *does* accept functions - allowing you to programmatically return the value of the list item).

You can see the appropriate code that deals with `search_fields` here (and it's limitations) on [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L349). The best you can do is follow relationships.

Answer (score 2):

In case others stumble upon this answer as I have, the accepted answer is no longer accurate. You can override the `get_search_results` function to search however you want.

[See the Django documentation on this function here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results)

Answer (score 0):

you should try it:

```
 search_fields s
```

After that, restart your service by: python manag.py runservice.